# In multilayer perceptron neural networks, is normalization required? or is optional? Why the network only seem to work when I use normalization?

Tags: neural-networks, normalisation

I followed the steps in the following article (which teaches how to program a multilayer perceptron neural network from scratch in Python): https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/.

Using the tutorial in article, i testing 3 different datasets: **seeds.csv (used as an example of the tutorial in the article itself)**, and also, **Iris.csv and diamonds_filtered.csv**, **I noticed that the neural network in the article In the various tests I did, the error gradually reduced consistently, in all data sets, but it only works when I use the normalization technique presented in the article**. **When I run the script without using normalization, the error during training becomes very high and reaches a point that does not decrease**, even if many epochs pass. Therefore, **the conclusion I reached is that this neural network was only successful using normalization on the dataset.**

**The datasets I downloaded are here:**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/wheat-seeds.csv
https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/Iris.csv
https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/diamonds_filtered.csv

**I know normalization is used to transform the data to a similar scale**. I searched the internet and some sources say that if there are entries in the dataset that have very large or **very small values, this can cause convergence problems.**

So about normalization, **I have a question: in the samples from these 3 data sets that I used (without using normalization), how can I know if there are very high or very small entries? How can I check this better? Is there any step by step I can do to check this?**

**And i also have another question about this: is normalization required or is optional?**

**Is it common and expected that a multilayer perceptron neural network can only learn and reduce error if normalization has been performed on the input data?**

**Why is this neural network only able to reduce error and generalize when I use normalization?**